# percentage of members enrolled in another program

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the percentage of members enrolled in a program. Membership date and enrollment date columns are available. I wrote something like this but it calcultes 100% for some reason. Any help is appreciated:

```
Measure =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'table'[MemberNbr] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'table' ),
            table[EnrollmentDate] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date].[Date] )
        )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'table'[MemberAgreeNbr] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'table' ),
            table[MembershipDate] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date].[Date] )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: Have you tried to get cumulative values for some reason?